# Buildozer - Orientation Portrait setting not working

Tags: python, kivy, orientation, buildozer, portrait

I am a Python Kivy learner. As part of learning, 2 months back i successfully build a calculator app through google collab. The app was working perfectly. Now when i build the same app, it builds successfully but the orientation doesnt work. It rotates to all direction.

orientation = portrait

doesnt seem to work now.

I tried building other apps too recently through google collab, and the same orientation problem persist. Anyone recently built app through collab successfully without the orientation problem?

Comment: Buildozer.spec 's orientation = portrait settings is not working anymore in recent google collab builds. The android app keeps changing orientation after build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import os

os.environ["KIVY_ORIENTATION"] = "Portrait"

adding this at the top of the main.py solves the issue.